# 404 on admin after I changed a base URL

Tags: admin, backend, 404

I'm posting this question again since all the existing related posts are pretty old! I am completely new to Magento and I had just started to change a few config settings when I started to get a 404 on the admin. Site loads fine it's the admin I have issues with. I was setting up stores fine but I changed a Base URL (secure) saved and got a 404 afterwards. I have no idea whatsoever how to fix this and I need my admin back!
I appreciate all the help I can get!
Thanks,

Comment: Hi, Can you please check is there any .htaccess file available on your project root directory ?

Comment: Yes, there is an  .htaccess file.

Comment: Did you enabled URL rewrite ?

Comment: im not 100% sure but im pretty sure I didn't,  since I was changing settings just to see the results. I never imagined there was a config change that would prevent me to go back to the admin and change it back!

Comment: can you please run your URL with index.php like www.example.com/index.php/admin

Comment: that's exactly how I run it (with the URL that my hosting provided me) ie http://testmagento.mascoticosas.com/index.php/vcb6pmmd9bhal649

Comment: Yes, Right after that, it is working?

Comment: What I understand here. After changing system configuration you are not able to open admin and that will redirect you on 404 page. Am I right here ?

Comment: I think you've changed this configuration from **No** to **Yes**. 

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4301150/ba9b8439564703b962074168486593f0

Comment: right! specifically, I changed a base URL before this issue started

Comment: Can you please confirm last screenshot's value you've changed there ? So I can provide you exact solution here.

Comment: yes, that could be it. Not 100% sure since I was just experimenting! haha

Comment: I cannot confirm since I can't get into the admin but It could be it

Comment: Okay I'll add my answer in 5 mins. Please give me some time.

Comment: sure! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I've updated my answer, Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open you Database in phpmyadmin and then select your DB there and run this query there.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml';
```

After this please run below commands to clear cache..

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

That's it. After doing this you can open your admin page.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if this solution works for you or not ?

Comment: Approve my answer if above solution works for you.

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot!!! I really appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks you too Buddy. Happy to help you! 